# how extract membership vector for my GNgraph in r?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, nmi

i want to use NMI to compare my algorithm in community detection with other methods.so i am making some graphs with `sample_sbm()` which i define to give me 10 nodes ,and in `block.sizes=c(3,3,4)` part i define to have  communities,first one has 3members,second 3,third 4 members.
now i want a membership vector of them.it should be : 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3

what is the best way to do it?i was thinking of taking 3 arguments c1,c2,c3 and then using them in block.sizes(),so i can use a for loop to build the membership vector.but looks a bit dirty.cause the number of communities should be arbitrary. 
i will be thankful if you suggest me something nicer

```
library(igraph)
p<-cbind( c(1, 0,0), c(0, 1,0) ,c(0,0,1))
g <- sample_sbm(10, pref.matrix=p, block.sizes=c(3,3,4) )


#comunity detection algorithm
wc <- cluster_walktrap(g)
modularity(wc)

a=membership(wc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE following the original question-asker's comments:**

I store the sizes of the blocks in a `my_block_sizes` vector. Then I use the `rep.int` function and the `seq_along` function to create the membership vector according to the sizes of the blocks.

```
library(NMI)
library(igraph)

my_block_sizes <- c(3,3,4)

# make a membership vector
membership_vector <- rep.int(seq_along(my_block_sizes), my_block_sizes)
membership_vector
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3

p <- cbind(c(1,0,0), c(0,1,0), c(0,0,1))
g <- igraph::sample_sbm(10, pref.matrix=p, block.sizes=my_block_sizes)

# comunity detection algorithm
wc <- cluster_walktrap(g)
modularity(wc)

a <- membership(wc)
```

**Original answer:**

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're after, but based on the information you've provided, this may solve your problem.

I use the length of the `wc` object to determine the number of communities detected by the community detection algorithm, and the `rep.int` function to repeat each community number according to the size of the blocks, which I store in advance in the `my_block_sizes` object.

```
library(NMI)
library(igraph)

my_block_sizes <- c(3,3,4)

p <- cbind(c(1,0,0), c(0,1,0), c(0,0,1))
g <- igraph::sample_sbm(10, pref.matrix=p, block.sizes=my_block_sizes)


#comunity detection algorithm
wc <- cluster_walktrap(g)
modularity(wc)

a <- membership(wc)

# make a membership vector
membership_vector <- rep.int(1:length(wc), my_block_sizes)
membership_vector
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: yes yes it works.but  there is only one point.i should have membership_vector for my graph before using algorithms ! but luckily its equal to number of nodes which it is first argument of sample_sbm()function.so i can save it as my_n and then use your method, thank you

Comment: Glad that this answer helped you. Please do accept this answer if it solves your problem. Otherwise I'm happy to help further. I'm afraid I don't quite understand what determines the `membership_vector`. It sounds like the length of the vector is equal to the first argument of the `sample_sbm` function, but what determines how many communities/integer membership values there are? For example, you have three membershp values: 1, 2, 3 - how is that determined? If you can tell me where those numbers come from, I can update my solution to help you further.

Comment: yes it is what i need was that rep.int () `function.rep.int(seq_along(my_block_sizes), my_block_sizes)` .this code work so please replace it cause i am going to accept your answer.andlength of 
my_block_sizes is the number of my communities which it is 3 here.so i just want my membership_vector shows 3 first nodes are in one community(number1),3other are in one community (number2)and 4th other are in same community (number3).